# Compiling MySQL C++ programs on Windows 10

Tags: c++, mysql, windows, gcc

Sorry if this has been answered before but I am struggling to find a simple solution to this problem.

My end goal is to be able to import user-defined aggregate functions into MySQL. In order to do this, I need to use C++. I already have the C++ Connector installed, but I'm not sure how to compile my program using the libraries contained within the connector on Windows. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: It's all in the manual [UDF Compiling and Installing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/udf-compiling.html)

Comment: This is waaay too broad.

Comment: _Small Note_ What has GCC got to do with compiling on Windows? Are you talking about compiling for MINGW or somehting like it?

Comment: *"What has GCC got to do with compiling on Windows? Are you talking about compiling for MINGW or somehting like it?"* Well @RiggsFolly GCC should be able to run on Cygwin..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I could not remember the cygwin acronym, thansk for the memory jogger, but that is what I ment by _Something like it_ :)